# Windows APIs - Prohibited by License for Use With Mono?

Tags: .net, windows, dll, mono

Long time lurker, first time question-asker.

I have a problem where I need to be able to decompile DLLs built to run on Windows...but I need to do it on Linux...inside a non-interactive, automated tool. I've solved this dilemma by grabbing the ILSpy source code, tearing off the GUI, hammering the ILSpy EXE into a DLL, writing a CLI for it, building and running it under Mono. It works great, but there are licensing questions.

I asked our resident licensing authority "Is this an acceptable use of the MIT-licensed ILSpy, for our purposes?" The core of his answer was

*The MIT license is no problem. But there can be problems running .NET apps using Mono. If they require any Windows DLLs, you probably can’t do it, since most Windows DLLs explicitly say that they can only be run on Windows operating systems. We had to [go to great lengths to] avoid trying to use Windows APIs [on another project] when it was running under Mono.*

Then he left the company. Sweet. Does anyone know whether the "standard" .NET DLLs (System, System.Core, etc.) are really restricted to Windows platforms? If so, how is it possible to write any non-trivial .NET app for Mono? The solution has to be rebuilt with Mono to run on Mono - does that process link to Mono DLLs in lieu of MS DLLs?

I've looked here and on the Interwebulator for the answer, but all I've found is questions/answers about Mono licensing. I appreciate anyone's insight on the topic.

Comment: Mono provides its own version of System, System.Core, etc.  They don't have a Windows dependency.  Whether it is acceptable to decompile DLLs for which you don't own the source is also obvious.  It never is.

Comment: We do own the source. Why are we decompiling then? The gory details are much too long to go into here. Thank you for your insight - as a mono noob, it's very helpful.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm fairly sure there are parts of the world where reverse engineering is a protected activity.  So it isn't quite as cut and dried as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Whether an application can be ported to Mono and run on another OS other than Windows, is subject to two keys,

1. Whether any of its dependencies are available on Mono.
2. Whether some source code is licensed only for Windows.

The two can be related, but also can be not. Below is a few examples,

**The dependency can be used on Mono, but the license does not permit**

A long time ago, Microsoft decided to publish MEF source code for its users, but only licensed that under Windows usage (yes, that means it is not the open source under OSI terms). You can find the story at Miguel's blog,

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Sep-07.html

Of course, we see Microsoft soon changed their minds to switch to a fully OSI compliant license,

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Oct-02.html

Thus, if you are moving any app to Mono, please carefully analyze the dependency licensing. If any third party vendor makes a Windows only license to you, you have to discuss with them.

**Licensing is OK, but the code just fails on Mono**

This is the more often case, such as [DockPanel Suite](http://dockpanelsuite.com).

The code is fully open source under MIT, but it heavily depends on Win32 API to achieve focus/drag & drop related operations, so cannot be fully ported to Mono.

Similarly, I believe ILSpy (as well as its dependencies) is fully open source and has no restriction to be used only on Windows. Why most people think that ILSpy is Windows only, is because that ILSpy guys chose to use WPF to build the UI, which limited its primary user base to Windows.

If you use GTK# or another UI framework to build a cross platform UI, its core functionality can go to anywhere you like.